# Javascript empty array and empty object equivalent in PHP

Tags: javascript

What will be the equivalent of the following JavaScript code in PHP:

```
[""]
```

and

```
{0 : ""}
```

Comment: Note that neither the array, nor the object are empty.

Comment: [Literally the first result when Googling "PHP array"](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first one is an Array of one element, being the element an empty string. In PHP it'd be `[""]` or `array("")`.

```
<?php
$a = [""];
var_dump($a); // array(1) { [0]=> string(0) "" }

$b = array("");
var_dump($b); // array(1) { [0]=> string(0) "" }
```

The second is an object with empty string value for key `0`. In PHP it could be represented as: `(object)[""]` or `(object)[0 => ""]`.

```
<?php
$a = (object)[""];
var_dump($a);  // object(stdClass)#1 (1) { [0]=> string(0) "" }

$b = (object)[0=>""];
var_dump($b);  // object(stdClass)#2 (1) { [0]=> string(0) "" }

// Also:

$c = new \stdClass;
$c->{0} = "";
var_dump($c);  // object(stdClass)#3 (1) { ["0"]=> string(0) "" }
```

Please, read about [PHP Arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) and [PHP Objects](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.object.php).